# When should a minor be the one lighting the Chanuka candles?

Tags: chanuka, riddle, minor-katan-child

When should a minor L'Chatchila be the one lighting the Chanuka candles?

Answer (score 2):

The Yalkut Yosef in the name of the Moadei Hashem page 117: mentions that when lighting the Chanuka candles in Shul there is L'Chatchila supposed to be a Minyan there. He mentions that you can include children into this Minyan, and if you do include children into this Minyan then you should L'Chatchila Davka have a child light the Menora.